# В 17 строке пишет: "Встречено 'else', а ожидалось ';' "

Tags: pascal

```
Var
    i, n: integer;
    q, q_temp, q_below_1: string;
    x, max_below_1: real;
    tr: boolean;
Begin
    max_below_1:=0;
    writeln('Введите количество чисел');
    readln(n);
    for i:=1 to N do begin
        write('Введите '); write(i); writeln(' число');
        readln(x);
        if x >= 1.0 then
          tr:=true;
          str(i,q_temp);
            q:=q + q_temp + ' '
        else if (tr <> true) and (x > max_below_1) then //Ошибка здесь.Что не так?
          str(i,q_below_1);
    end;
    if tr=false
        then write(q_below_1)
    else write(q)
end.
```

Comment: Это значит, что вы пропустили точку запятой перед этим.

Comment: Но это полбеды. Этому else не к чему привязаться, вы забыли пару begin/end для выражения `if then`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i:=1 to N do begin
    write('Введите '); write(i); writeln(' число');
    readln(x);
    if x >= 1.0 then begin // !!
      tr:=true;
      str(i,q_temp);
        q:=q + q_temp + ' ';
    end // !!
    else if (tr <> true) and (x > max_below_1) then
```

P.S. Как сапожник из пушкинского стихотворения, позволю себе дать совет: ставьте `begin`/`end` в начало строк ограничивающих блок кода.

```
for i := 1 to N do 
begin
  WriteLn('Введите ', i, ' число'); 
  ReadLn(x);
  if x >= 1.0 then 
  begin
    tr := true;
    Str(i, q_temp);
    q := q + q_temp + ' ';
  end
  else if (tr <> true) and (x > max_below_1) then 
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: а после end разве не нужен семиколон?

Comment: @vp_arth не перед `else` - одно из милых правил Паскаля

Comment: "одно из милых правил Паскаля" - да нормальное правило. ))

Comment: Если написать `end else ...`, то это правило становится вполне очевидным. Вы же перед `then` и `do` его тоже не ставите.